# select.remove() method works weird

Tags: javascript

so i'm working with javascript in AgilePoint.
and i've implied function that removes certain options from dropdown menu but eventually it's pretty weird. this is code for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmzTL.png)

so here i made simple condition, and if it's true so i want to remove the first option, the third and the forth. but in the end, it removes the first, and the forth. and the third(2) is still there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nrsM.png)

the last option needs to be deleted too, but i can't understand why it ignores from the second line.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is, if you remove the 0th element by running:

```
select.remove(0);
```

The 2nd and 3rd elements are no longer 2nd and 3rd but 1st and 2nd because the 0th element was removed.

Quick solution is to remove from largest index to the lowest:

```
select.remove(3);
select.remove(2);
select.remove(0);
```

Comment: btw, i have another question sorry if i'm bothering.
Now i'm trying to call other function that checks if certain textbox equal to the number 2, so i need to remove the options like i did above. but it seems to ignore the condition and it removes it no matter what.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it and post your other question as a separate one.

Comment: var select = document.getElementById("BigLoan");
  var vetek = document.getElementById("eVetek");
    
  if(vetek = '2')

- this is the code, i think my condition is bad.

Comment: Ok, please post your question and post link here and I'll take a look.